# group 2+ mock.patch into one

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, python-mock

Say I have:

```
import mock
...

@mock.patch("function_1")
@mock.patch("function_2")
def my_test(self, f1, f2):
    f1.return_value="foo"
    f2.return_value="bar"
    ...
```

function_1 and function_2 are very similar and mocked out in multiple test functions. I would love to modularize this pattern (of patching the two functions). Is there such a way? The ideal outcome would look something like below.

```
@grouppatch("function_1_and_2")
def my_test(self):
    ...
```

Comment: You could write your own decorator that takes a list of function names to patch then patches each one. If you really want to use a string like "function_1_and_2" (seems cumbersome imo) you can just parse it yourself into the two function names and patch each one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a function that takes target objects to be patched as parameters, and returns a decorator function that iterates through the target objects to use `mock.patch` to patch the object for the decorated function:

```
def grouppatch(*targets):
    def decorator(func):
        for target in targets:
            func = mock.patch(target)(func)
        return func
    return decorator
```

so that:

```
@grouppatch('builtins.bool', 'builtins.int')
def my_test(mock_bool, mock_int):
    mock_bool.return_value = True
    mock_int.return_value = 100
    print(bool(False), int(10))

my_test()
```

outputs:

```
True 100
```